# Is git-svn in the 10.04 repos broken?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, development

Has anyone seen problems with `git-svn` not installing properly from synaptic in 10.04? Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you be more specific - I use `Git` on 10.04 without issue. Any error messages, details, etc would be more helpful.

Comment: Note to self - check lauchpad.net first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, it's the `git-xxxx` format for git commands has been depreciated. `git svn` seems to work.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git-core/+bug/598593